# How to do a function on OCaml arrays?

Tags: arrays, ocaml

If I have an array like the following:

```
[| [|One; Zero; Zero; Zero; One; One; One; One|] 
   [|One; Zero; Zero; Zero; One; One; One; One|] |]
```

How do I convert this array to:

```
[| [|"10001111"|] [|"10001111"|] |]
```

Comment: I don't see why you need the inner arrays in the result; they look redundant.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have a type something like this:

```
type zo = Zero | One
```

You can convert like this:

```
let zos = function Zero -> "0" | One -> "1"

let zoaas zoaa =
    Array.map (fun a -> String.concat " " (Array.to_list (Array.map zos a))) zoaa
```

(I removed the inner arrays, they seem redundant as I said.)